# Согласование с числительным

Tags: согласование

В предложении :«Просрочит четыре и более платежа» или «Просрочит четыре и более платежей». Склоняюсь к первой версии: четыре платежА.

Comment: Я бы вообще "проскочат" написал для начала

Comment: Зачем «проскочат»?

Comment: Потому что множественное число. Или у вас что там подлежащее?

Comment: С единственным числом нужно "или", поскольку четыре **и** более (четырех) платеж**ей** одновременно один плательщик просрочить не может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: Просрочит **четыре и более платежа**

1. Розенталь  http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm

п.6. В сочетаниях два (три, четыре) и более... управляемое существительное ставится в родительном падеже единственного числа: два и более варианта, три и более трудных формы, четыре и более ценных предложения, т.е. существительное ставится в зависимость от числительных два, три, четыре, а не от слова более (ср. возможность перестановки: два варианта и более).

2. Грамота.ру

Вопрос № 282475
Добрый день. Бизнес, которым владеют два и более человек (два и более человека?)
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
В сочетаниях два (три, четыре) и более... управляемое существительное ставится в род. падеже ед. числа:  два и более человека. Ср.: два человека и более.

3. Студопедия  https://studopedia.info/5-110595.html

п.6. В сочетаниях два (три, четыре) и более... управляемое существительное ставится в родительном падеже единственного числа: два и более варианта, три и более трудных формы, четыре и более ценных предложения, т.е. существительное ставится в зависимость от числительных два, три, четыре, а не от слова более (ср. возможность перестановки: два варианта и более).

Comment: Да, странно... А у Пушкина тогда ошибка, получается?

Comment: @behemothus В подобных перечислениях (типа **два, три и более**) лучше использовать множественное число. Пример из книги того же Розенталя: *Наряду со словами однозначными в русском языке много слов, имеющих два, три и более **значений**.* Кстати, в большинстве учебников Розенталя процитированное в ответе правило даётся не настолько категорично: "управляемое существительное **обычно** ставится в родительном падеже".

Comment: Мнение Розенталя:  В области орфографии  (в отличие от пунктуации), желательна и необходима полная унификация. Соответственно,  это академические справочники указывают нам, что лучше делать, или хотя бы должны указывать.  Поэтому,  как я полагаю,  лучше придерживаться мнения официальных источников, хотя в текстах могут наблюдаться варианты.  Но пока они не нормированы, их могут отнести (и относят) к лексическим ошибкам (некорректная сочетаемость слов).

Comment: @grizzly  *В подобных перечислениях (типа два, три и более)*  - ну это уже что-то. Однако в Нацкорпусе есть же и примеры "из прошлого" без перечислений, пусть не столь авторитетные, но все-таки достаточно убедительные.  Управление это имеется не в каждой губернии; нередко оно распространяет свою власть на две и более губерний. [В. М. Грибовский. Государственное устройство и управление Российской Империи (1912)]

Comment: @Sharon я не очень понимаю эту вашу логику. В отчете вы даете ссылку на безальтернативное императивное правило, а в комментах говорите о каких-то вариантах.  давайте определимся, или это правило прямого действия и не имеющее оговорок, или у Розенталя приведен не всеобъемлющий и не самодостаточный его вариант.

Comment: Я говорю о НЕНОРМАТИВНЫХ вариантах, которые встречались в речи ранее и которые можно встретить и сейчас. Однако в официальных источниках я не вижу, чтобы их считали нормой. Если у вас есть сведения об этом, было бы интересно узнать.  По поводу вариантов мне больше нечего сказать. Это авторская (ненормированная) орфография, а на некоторых ресурсах вариант мн.числа приводят как пример лексической ошибки. Я считаю, что надо строго соблюдать существующие правила, нравятся они нам или нет.

Answer (score 0):

***Четыре и более платежей.***
"Четыре платежа" - да, но общее правило таково, что в числительном управляет последнее слово. Хотя при инверсии (если считаемая величина выносится вперед), то возможно иное:
*проcрочит платежа три и более.*

Нашел в нацкорпусе всего одну бесспорную цитату. Но какую!

> Чиновники получают по чинам своим ***по два, по три и более*** участков. [А. С. Пушкин.
> История Пугачева (1833)]

(здесь и далее - курсив мой. b-s)

И на инверсию тоже есть примеры.

> Какое тут множество цветов, и так прекрасных, что я прыгаю от радости
> при виде их и ни для чего в свете не могу удержаться, чтоб не достать
> себе одну из роз, так высоко растущих, как мне никогда еще не
> случалось видеть; эти деревца вышиною ***аршина три и более*** осыпаны
> прелестнейшими розами, и я не иначе могу доставать их, как срубя
> цветок концом сабли. [Н. А. Дурова. Кавалерист-девица (1835)]

> Прочих Полков сверх сего, при Царствующем Санктпетербурге, всегда
> бывает ***Полка по два, по три,*** и более. [А. И. Богданов. Описание
> Санктпетербурга (1751)]

Про инверсию вспомнил еще и потому, что очень согласен с @Alex_ander.

> четыре и более (четырех) платежей одновременно один плательщик
> просрочить не может.

Оно, конечно, так, но логика языка несколько отличается от математического логики  высказываний. "И" в конструкции "четыре и более" не означает одновременного выполнения двух несовместимых требований, а всего лишь подводит под единое правило ситуации "четыре" и "более четырех". так что ваш вывод про единственное число сам по себе неверен, хотя и приводит к правдоподобному результату.

Answer (score 0):

*Четыре платежа* — это [счётный оборот](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/587/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5).
После наречия [**более**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5) (в значении *больше*) счетный оборот должен стоять в родительном падеже, причем множественного числа (кроме, естественно, оборота с числительным "один"; такая связь называется [управлением](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/782-32_osobennosti_upravleniya_v_russkom_yazyke.html)):
два метра — более двух метров;
три рубля — более трех рублей;
четыре платежа — более четырех платежей.

Во избежание повторов пишут так (не вдаемся в смысл куска предложения):
**четыре** [платежа] **и более** [четырех] **платежей**;
**четыре платежа и более** [четырех платежей].

> Социальное дистанцирование не поможет: коронавирус может преодолевать **4 и более метров.**

Comment: *Во избежание повторов пишут так (не вдаемся в смысл куска предложения):* сдается мне, что вы неправильно диагноз ставите. Пишут так не во избежание повторов, а по причине того, что такая конструкция воспринимается как аналог вполне принятого в математике отношения "больше или рано" (т.е. "не менее чем"). Сейчас его часто обозначают как "4+". Ну при чем тут повторы-то?!