# Жили у бабуси два веселых... гусей?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, управление, числительные

*Жили у бабуси два веселых гуся.*

Но в [словаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C) что-то не нашел такого слова во множественном числе.
Или это разговорное слово — гуся (два)? И два гуся — неправильно, а правильно — двое гусей?

Comment: См. по ссылке. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462584/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc

Comment: @NikVladi Спасибо за весёленький вопрос! С наступающим праздником!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое.
Предложение из песни пишется без запятой: *Жили у бабуси два весёлых гуся*.

Второе.
Конечно же, такая форма слова (*гу́ся*) **есть** — Р. п., ед. ч.

Третье.
*Весёлый гусь* — это словосочетание (прилагательное и существительное).

*Два гуся* — это [счётный оборот](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/587/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5) (количественное числительное и существительное в форме родительного падежа).
При числительных ***два**, три, четыре* существительные ставятся **в родительном падеже единственного числа**: два кота, два лебедя, два стула, два медведя, два глаза.

*Два весёлых гуся* — определение находится между числительным и существительным.
При существительных **мужского** и среднего рода определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, ставится **в родительном падеже множественного числа**: два белых кота, два черных лебедя, два венских стула, два злых медведя.

На светло-бирюзовом атласе **два белых голубя** прижимаются друг к другу. [Зинаида Синявская. Пазлы // «Сибирские огни», 2013]

По кругу знаки зодиака, затем созвездия Девы, Андромеды, Медведица Большая и Малая, ещё что-то подобное же, а внизу **два чёрных сфинкса** и огромная триумфальная арка с Дворцовой площади. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 1 (1978)]

Итоговое.
Так что всё правильно в этой детской песенке. Как и в этой:
*И уносят меня, и уносят меня

В звенящую снежную даль

**Три белых коня**, эх, три белых коня —

Декабрь,  январь и февраль!*

[Сочетания количественных числительных с именами существительными](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/106-sochetaniya-kolichestvennyih-chislitelnyih-69172.html)
[Согласование определения с существительным, зависящим от числительных «два», «три», «четыре»](https://psyera.ru/soglasovanie-opredeleniya-s-sushchestvitelnym-zavisyashchim-ot-chislitelnyh-dva-tri-chetyre_8718.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Собирательные числительные сочетаются с названиями молодых животных, например: *двое медвежат, трое щенят* (Розенталь, Справочник по правописанию и стилистике, § 165) и не сочетаются с наименованиями взрослых особей, например: *трое котов, семеро козлов* (о животных)([Грамота Ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=295604)).

Таким образом, правильно будет *два-три-четыре **гуся***, несмотря на то, что в словаре такой формы нет.

Примеры:

- Там бродили два гуся да пяток кур (Гончаров);
- ― Ну что вы там опять друг на друга шипите, словно два гуся? (Носов).

Comment: *Таким образом, правильно будет два-три-четыре гуся, несмотря на то, что в словаре такой формы нет.* Вы и вправду так считаете?

Comment: Я имел в виду — нет с пометой "мн. ч.", что и искал автор вопроса.

Comment: Просто Ваш ответ никоим образом не объясняет, **почему** же правильно именно *два весёлых гуся*, а не "два весёлых гусей".

Comment: А этого автор и не спрашивал. У Розенталя тоже, кстати, в процитированном мной справочнике никак не объясняется *почему*. Просто дана информация.

Comment: М-м, разве? По умолчанию — спрашивал. Читайте: *Жили у бабуси, два веселых... гусей?* и *два гуся — неправильно*? Речь ведь идет не о собирательном числительном, а о количественном — два.

Comment: Я и ответил: "...правильно будет *два-три-четыре гуся*". И аргументировал цитатой и ссылкой. По-моему, предельно по существу вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

В сочетании с числительным ‟два”, как и с числительными ‟три”, ‟четыре”, существительные ставятся в форму родительного падежа и единственного числа, а не в множественную форму родительного падежа.
Не со всеми числительными больше единицы существительные ставятся в множественную форму, — например, с числительными, в разряде единиц которых находится единица, существительные ставятся в форму единственного числа и именительного падежа, как ‟двадцать один гусь”, ‟семьсот двадцать одно дерево”.