# Какое согласование в числе будет правильным для сочетания два (три, четыре) и более?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, числительные

**Вот два предложения:**

1. Станислав Иванов, 2013. *Когда всем знакомым людям я написал **по два и более раза,** то принялся за общественные организации, политические коалиции и транснациональные корпорации.*
2. Захар Прилепин. Санькя (2006). Если встречи члена партии с женщиной повторяются **два и более раз**, он должен избить ее.

Согласование в этих примерах **разное**, а как правильно? Этот вопрос часто задают пользователи. Правило известное, оно есть **[у Розенталя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm):** §166. Сочетания числительных с существительным, пункт 6.

В сочетаниях ***два (три, четыре) и более..***. управляемое существительное ставится в родительном падеже **единственного числа**: два и более варианта, три и более трудных формы, четыре и более ценных предложения, т.е. существительное ставится в зависимость от числительных два, три, четыре, а не от слова более (ср. возможность перестановки: два варианта и более).

Но вопросы все равно остаются. Вот и [на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462584/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC) **уже обсуждался** этот вопрос, да и правило было приведено. Но многие участники были **недовольны таким решением,** приводили различные доводы. В Сети мне встретилась [тема](https://wmbild.ru/kak-pravilno-govorit-dva-i-bolee-raz-ili-dva-i-bolee-raza/), где говорилось, что оба варианта возможны, но есть очень тонкие смысловые различия (понять эти различия было сложно).

В результате пришлось еще раз подумать **о правильности решения**, и определенное мнение у меня есть. А как думаете вы, **прав ли Розенталь?**

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу для обсуждения свой вариант ответа.

1. **Согласование в ед. числе** надо применять в следующих случаях:

(1) Вы хотите следовать **строгой норме**, чтобы не было никаких проблем.

(2) Вы **не видите смысловой разницы** между вариантами, поэтому из двух формальных решений (с перестановкой) выбираете вариант Розенталя.

2. Допустим, что вы видите какие-то **смысловые оттенки** и делаете выбор мн. числа по смыслу.  А в чем этот смысл заключается?
3. Рассмотрим пример: ***просрочит четыре и более платежа***.

В случае ед. числа мы ориентируемся на такую запись: ***четыре платежа и более*** . В случае мн. числа —  **четыре и более платежей**.

Я не вижу здесь смысловой разницы: если просрочил **хотя бы четыре платежа**, то начинаешь платить штрафные санкции, а до этого их не платишь.

4. Думаю, что все попытки объяснить выбор мн. числа будут такими же **формальными, а не смысловыми.** А тогда лучше выбрать формальный вариант Розенталя и не нарушать норму.

Удивительно, но Розенталь **всегда прав**))